# How do I change a value in the ModelState, so that it will be valid, using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently allowing a selectlist to have an initial value of "".  The user can choose whether to fill in this option or leave it on the default value.

This selectList works on an ID, where the ID is passed to my controller.  However, as an int is not being selected, the ModelState results in False as the input was an empty string rather than an int.

I want to change the value of this empty string to be 0.  This would result in the ModelState being True.  I have been looking at the ModelState dictionary class, so that I can change the key, value pair before the ModelState is checked.   However, I have been unable to use this successfully.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary(v=vs.118).aspx

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you not make the int property nullable like `public int?`

Comment: You can play with Model binder, you can set default value for this property, you can add a pair of values with `"" - 0` pair added to collection before you generate the view etc. Question is how do you create the view and how data model passed on there looks like?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("PropertyID", new ValueProviderResult("New value", "", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Here is a usefull article.

http://geekswithblogs.net/BobHardister/archive/2013/03/11/retain-and-set-posted-checkbox-value-in-the-mvc-4.aspx

Answer (score 10):

you could just remove the error

```
if (ModelState.ContainsKey("{key}"))
    ModelState["{key}"].Errors.Clear();

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful to use after changing the value.  As I found when the value is changed, the related error still remains. :)